# Exporting an SCL class definition to external file

Tags: sas, sas-af

As part of a redevelopment project I am looking to extract all source code for a legacy SCL application.

Following Richard DeVenezia's excellent [tip](http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/af/index.php?topic=15#4) I have successfully been able to export all SCL and SOURCE entries using the following command:

```
BUILD %8b.%32b.%32b.%8b; FILE "C:\TEMP\%8b.%32b.%32b.%8b"; CANCEL
```

I was also able to write some SCL to extract / export all the SLISTS.  The final piece is CLASS definitions..

Using Explorer I can open a CLASS entry into a GUI which shows the methods and attributes.  I can also LIST the results to the log.  However, all the methods are empty (there is no source code), eg:

```
/* SET_VIEW */
SET_VIEW: method / (signature='n');
endmethod;
```

Am not sure if this is always the case, or that the classes I have checked (about 10) all just happen to have empty methods.

My question is:

**How do I export a CLASS definition from catalog entry to text file?**

Comment: I don't know the first thing about SCL, but - have you considered PROC CATALOG?

Comment: proc catalog will happily display the entries (`et=class`) but not the contents of those entries!

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  There is a `CREATESCL()` function (see [doc](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sclref/67564/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0bkywqdy5agu3n1qucv482enxc3.htm)) that will let you convert your CLASS into an SCL entry - which can then be exported to a text file.

Example (SCL) code:

```
rc = createscl('sashelp.classes.checkbox_c.class','work.a.b.scl');
```

My explanation of how to [run SCL in EG](http://www.rawsas.blogspot.com/2017/05/create-compile-run-scl-in-enterprise.html) may also be of interest in running the above.

To export to a text file, simply run (in Base SAS):

```
dm 'build work.a.b.scl; file "C:\temp\sashelp.classes.checkbox_c.class"; cancel';
```